# Difference between java and C# doubles

Tags: c#, java, mono

`double` is a type that represents 64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point number in Java

`double` is a type that represents 64-bit double-precision number in IEEE 754 format in C#.

Both languages follow the same specification. So why there is difference in following code? I checked Mono as well.

```
Double.MIN_VALUE == (Double.MIN_VALUE + 1.0); // false
```

[Java ideone](http://ideone.com/2sgi3K)

```
Console.WriteLine(Double.MinValue == (Double.MinValue + 1.0)); // true
```

[C# ideone](http://ideone.com/lPdAGA)

Comment: oh MIN_VALUE is C#'s Epsilon?

Comment: I suggest you read what these constants return.  While some research was done, the documentation wasn't checked, which is a required step for a good question.

Comment: Slightly off topic but you are asking about differences... In Java "The Double class wraps a value of the primitive type double in an object. An object of type Double contains a single field whose type is double."  But in .NET "all floating-point numeric types are value types" so double and Double are interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's `Double.MIN_VALUE` is `2^-1074`

while

C#'s `Double.MinValue` is `-1.7976931348623157E+308`

They have different values because they follow a different semantic.

[In Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) :

> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double

[In C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.minvalue.aspx) :

> Represents the smallest possible value of a Double [...] The value of this constant is negative 1.7976931348623157E+308

Answer (score 4):

C#'s [Double.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.double.minvalue.aspx) : *The value of this constant is **negative 1.7976931348623157E+308.***

Java's [Double.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE): *A constant holding the **smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2-1074.***